# Error processing multiple files

Tags: awk

I'm trying to process 10 files with `awk` in my script, and I'm getting the following error.

```
$ sh skipper.sh file1 filea fileb filec filec fileb filea fileb filec fileb awk: cmd. line:2: (FILENAME=filec FNR=7) fatal: cannot open file `file10' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Does any one know how to fix it? It is working fine with <10 files but I need to use it 10 or 50 files.

Here is my code

```
awk -v nfiles="10" 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}
$0 in a {a[$0]++; next}
{b[$0]++}
END{
  for(i in a){
    if(a[i]==nfiles) {
      print i > "output1"
    }
    else if(a[i]==1) {
        print i > "output3"
    }
  }
  for(i in b){
    if(b[i]==nfiles-1) {
        print i > "output2"
    }
  }
}' $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 $10
```

Comment: This is not an awk problem. It is a shell problem. $10 is the first argument with a 0 after it not a 10th argument to the script. I suggest adding a tag for the shell you are using. Your shell might have something to repeat the entire command line instead of a single argument.

Comment: You should probably just use `"$@"`, rather than listing out all those positional parameters `$1 $2...`.

Answer (score 5):

When you hit argument 10 and above, you should use braces  eg

```
${10}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little modification of your code you can use any number of files, you need

```
awk 'BEGIN{nfiles=ARGC-1}
...
} "$@"
```

In this way You can enter any number of files to your awk script. It will process the empty files as well. If you want to skip the empty files You can use this:

```
awk 'FNR==1{++nfiles}
...
} "$@"
```